# Deploying web parts to sharepoint with out taking sharepoint down?

Tags: deployment

Is there a way to install sharepoint web parts with out taking sharepoint down at all?

Here is what I use for my deployment batch file:

@ECHO OFF
SET PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\BIN"

ECHO Deactivating Feature...
stsadm -o deactivatefeature -id ed9a2d2b-a773-4de0-a739-5dfce5f7c06e -url http://mysite.contoso.com/sites/Properties -force

ECHO Uninstalling Feature
stsadm -o uninstallfeature -filename MyWSP_Feature1\Feature.xml -force

ECHO Retracting Solution
stsadm -o retractsolution -name MyWSP.wsp -url http://mysite.contoso.com/sites/Properties -local

ECHO Deleting Solution
stsadm -o deletesolution -name MyWSP.wsp

ECHO Adding Solution
stsadm -o addsolution -filename MyWSP.wsp

ECHO Deploying Solution
stsadm -o deploysolution -name MyWSP.wsp -url http://mysite.contoso.com/sites/Properties -allowgacdeployment -local -force

ECHO Installing Feature
stsadm -o installfeature -filename MyWSP_Feature1\Feature.xml -force

ECHO Activating Feature
stsadm -o activatefeature -id ed9a2d2b-a773-4de0-a739-5dfce5f7c06e -url http://mysite.contoso.com/sites/Properties -force

iisreset

pause

Comment: Are these webparts belongs to a farm level solution or a sandbox solution?

Comment: Even without the IISRESET in the batch file you're going to be causing one as stsadm will update each web applications web.config file.

Comment: If you want to keep developing WebParts using Farm-Solutions you can come up with a concept of generic webpart which loads custom controls on demand from GAC. In which case you won't have to restart IIS to load new controls.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Sandbox solution, they do not require any downtime.

Sandbox solution are limited compare to farm solution but you should be able to do everything you need with it.

Comment: Consider Sandbox solution only if "minimal downtime" requirement is pretty important, as developing for Sandbox will add significant effort to your current workload.

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach that we took at an organisation, though it requires infrastructure to achieve the no downtime.

http://blog.ithinksharepoint.com/2012/07/16/deploying-sharepoint-wsp-solutions-without-downtime/

Regards
Simon